# postgreSQL check if the element exists in array with regex path in Jsonb

Tags: postgresql

I have a table with json:

column 1: c1 -> string

column 2: c2 -> integer

column 3: jsonb ->

```
{
  "o1": "hi",
  "o2": "hello",
  "o3": {
    "o3a": {
      "o3aa": {
        "id1": [
          "v1",
          "v2",
          "v3"
        ],
        "id2": [
          "v3"
        ],
        "id99": [
          "v99",
          "v2",
          "v3"
        ]
      }
    },
    "o3ab": true
  }
}
```

I need to check if jsonb -> o3 -> o3a -> o3aa -> ** contains 'v3'
bascially, I need to search for all ids that contains the 'v3'

I have tried the following:

```
`SELECT * FROM table where jsonb_path_exists(jsonb, '$.o3.o3a.o3aa.**');`
```

this would if the path to o3aa exsits. but I couldn't figure out how to make it works for the array.

```
`SELECT * FROM table where (jsonb -> 'o3' -> 'o3a' -> 'o3aa' @? '$[*] ? (@ > "v3")'))`
```

return me empty

Answer (score 2):

I think you need this `WHERE` condition:

```
WHERE jsonb_path_exists(
         jsonb,
         'strict $.o3.o3a.o3aa.*[*] ? (@ == "v3")'
      )
```

Read: contains attributes `o3` -> `o3a` -> `o3aa` -> (arbitrary name) that is an array, where an element of the array is `v3`.

Comment: thanks. this works for me. and the `strict ` really helps.